# Systematically iterate across multiple columns and rows of DF to output differing list sizes across multiple columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, loops, iteration

I'm hoping to iterate across this dataframe to increase the size of lists for Column `['B']` and Column `['C']`.  It isn't important to this example but these lists will be inputted into a function during each iteration.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a','a','b','b'],
                   'B' : ['1','2','1','2'],
                   'C' : ['2','3','1','6']})
```

By iterating across this dataframe, I hope to obtain something as follows:

(Starting with Column `['B']`)

```
[1]
[1,2]
[1,2,1]
[1,2,1,2]
```

(then Column `['C']`)

```
[2]
[2,3]
[2,3,1]
[2,3,1,6]
```

These lists will then be put into a function at the end of each iteration, but the issue I'm having is writing a proper for loop to code the list generation.

The second aspect of my question isn't as important...but it would be nice if I could also iteratively to output the value of `['A']` the list stops at (for example, when iterating across Column `['C']`, list `[2,3]` relates to `['A'] = 'b'` and the list from Column `['C']` of `[2,3,1]` relates to  `['A'] = 'b'`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little contrived, but this is probably the easiest way of doing it. Note that addition on lists is very expensive.

```
df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].values.reshape(-1, 2, 1).tolist()
df[['B', 'C']].cumsum()

              B             C
0           [1]           [2]
1        [1, 2]        [2, 3]
2     [1, 2, 1]     [2, 3, 1]
3  [1, 2, 1, 2]  [2, 3, 1, 6]
```

The trick is to augment the dimensionality of your array, so each element becomes a list with a single element. Once you assign back, you can call `df.cumsum` which operates row-wise and adds the lists together, cumulatively.

Comment: find another way inspired by your cumsum :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
df['B'],df['C']=df[['B','C']].values[::None].T.cumsum(axis=1)
df.applymap(list)
Out[1118]: 
     A             B             C
0  [a]           [1]           [2]
1  [a]        [1, 2]        [2, 3]
2  [b]     [1, 2, 1]     [2, 3, 1]
3  [b]  [1, 2, 1, 2]  [2, 3, 1, 6]
```

Updated

```
df[['B','C']]=df[['B','C']].applymap(list)
df
Out[1121]: 
   A             B             C
0  a           [1]           [2]
1  a        [1, 2]        [2, 3]
2  b     [1, 2, 1]     [2, 3, 1]
3  b  [1, 2, 1, 2]  [2, 3, 1, 6]
```

Comment: Nice one! Though it seems A is also converted to a list column.

Answer (score 2):

One other way about this would be to use an "expanding window" function:

```
>>> def expanding_window(obj):
        n = len(obj) + 1
        return [obj[:i] for i in range(1, n)]

>>> pd.DataFrame([expanding_window(df[k].tolist()) for k in df.columns], index=df.columns).T
              A             B             C
0           [a]           [1]           [2]
1        [a, a]        [1, 2]        [2, 3]
2     [a, a, b]     [1, 2, 1]     [2, 3, 1]
3  [a, a, b, b]  [1, 2, 1, 2]  [2, 3, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a for loop, you can do:

```
for col in ['B','C']:
    print([df[col].tolist()[:i+1] for i,v in enumerate(df[col].tolist())])

[['1'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '1'], ['1', '2', '1', '2']]
[['2'], ['2', '3'], ['2', '3', '1'], ['2', '3', '1', '6']]
```

For your 2nd question, is this what you are after?

```
for col in ['B','C']:
    print([df[col].tolist()[:i+1]+[df.A.iloc[i]] for i,v in enumerate(df[col].tolist())])

[['1', 'a'], ['1', '2', 'a'], ['1', '2', '1', 'b'], ['1', '2', '1', '2', 'b']]
[['2', 'a'], ['2', '3', 'a'], ['2', '3', '1', 'b'], ['2', '3', '1', '6', 'b']]
```